# Safety pictures at server

Tags: php, mysql, apache, security, gallery

I am trying to let useres upload their pictures at my website and I don't want to let others to see them, even if they know their URL. I would like to implement something like unaccesible folder at apache. (If it is possible from .htacess) I don't want to put them into database, because it slows server quite a lot (imo). Is there a solution? I saw something at FB, but its quite different league.

Comment: make the user login, thats how FB does it, if you dont know how to make a login system, there are many many many gallery scripts out there you could use instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable public access to a directory using the `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(?:images)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]
```

This would forward requests to the images folder to your `index.php` file.

This will only work if you have `mod_rewrite` enabled.

Also you could add a `.htaccess` file to the folder you would like to disable public access to and add the following rule.

```
deny from all
```

Comment: And will I be still able to use those images htrough a php script or so to show them at that webpage?

Comment: @MrDoda Yes of course :) You can still access the files using php and for example stream them to the user using readfile() http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Comment: Thanks a lot :) It was rly helpful